# How to visualize RNN/LSTM weights in Keras/TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visualization, recurrent-neural-network

I've come across research publications and Q&A's discussing a need for inspecting RNN weights; some related answers are in the right direction, suggesting `get_weights()` - but how do I actually visualize the weights *meaningfully*? Namely, LSTMs and GRUs have *gates*, and all RNNs have *channels* that serve as independent feature extractors - so how do I **(1)** fetch *per-gate* weights, and **(2)** plot them in an informative manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keras/TF build RNN weights in a well-defined order, which can be inspected from the source code or via `layer.__dict__` directly - then to be used to fetch *per-kernel* and *per-gate* weights; *per-channel* treatment can then be employed given a tensor's shape. Below code & explanations cover *every possible case* of a Keras/TF RNN, and should be easily expandable to any future API changes.

Also see visualizing RNN gradients, and an application to [RNN regularization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714407/rnn-regularization-which-component-to-regularize/58868383#58868383); unlike in the former post, I won't be including a simplified variant here, as it'd still be rather large and complex per the nature of weight extraction and organization; instead, simply view relevant source code in the repository (see next section).

---

**Code source**: [See RNN](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn) (this post included w/ bigger images), my repository; included are:

- Activations visualization
- Weights visualization
- Activations gradients visualization
- Weights gradients visualization
- Docstrings explaining all functionality
- Support for Eager, Graph, TF1, TF2, and `from keras` & `from tf.keras`
- Greater visual customizability than shown in examples

---

**Visualization methods**:

- **2D heatmap**: plot weight distributions per gate, per kernel, per direction; *clearly shows kernel-to-hidden relations*
- **histogram**: plot weight distributions per gate, per kernel, per direction; *loses context info*

---

**EX 1: uni-LSTM, 256 units, weights** -- `batch_shape = (16, 100, 20)` (input)
`rnn_histogram(model, 'lstm', equate_axes=False, show_bias=False)`
`rnn_histogram(model, 'lstm', equate_axes=True,  show_bias=False)`
`rnn_heatmap(model, 'lstm')`

- Top plot is a histogram subplot grid, showing weight distributions per kernel, and within each kernel, per gate
- Second plot sets `equate_axes=True` for an even comparison across kernels and gates, improving quality of comparison, but potentially degrading visual appeal
- Last plot is a heatmap of the same weights, with gate separations marked by vertical lines, and bias weights also included
- Unlike histograms, the heatmap *preserves channel/context information*: input-to-hidden and hidden-to-hidden transforming matrices can be clearly distinguished
- Note the large concentration of maximal values at the Forget gate; as trivia, in Keras (and usually), bias gates are all initialized to zeros, except the Forget bias, which is initialized to ones

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**EX 2: bi-CuDNNLSTM, 256 units, weights** -- `batch_shape = (16, 100, 16)` (input)
`rnn_histogram(model, 'bidir', equate_axes=2)`
`rnn_heatmap(model, 'bidir', norm=(-.8, .8))`

- Bidirectional is supported by both; biases included in this example for histograms
- Note again the bias heatmaps; they no longer appear to reside in the same locality as in EX 1. Indeed, `CuDNNLSTM` (and `CuDNNGRU`) biases are defined and initialized differently - something that can't be inferred from histograms

[image]
[image]

---

**EX 3: uni-CuDNNGRU, 64 units, weights gradients** -- `batch_shape = (16, 100, 16)` (input)
`rnn_heatmap(model, 'gru', mode='grads', input_data=x, labels=y, cmap=None, absolute_value=True)`

- We may wish to visualize *gradient intensity*, which can be done via `absolute_value=True` and a greyscale colormap
- Gate separations are apparent even without explicit separating lines in this example:

  - `New` is the most active kernel gate (input-to-hidden), suggesting more error correction on *permitting information flow*
  - `Reset` is the least active recurrent gate (hidden-to-hidden), suggesting least error correction on memory-keeping

[image]

---

**BONUS EX: LSTM NaN detection, 512 units, weights** -- `batch_shape = (16, 100, 16)` (input)

- Both the heatmap and the histogram come with built-in NaN detection - kernel-, gate-, and direction-wise
- Heatmap will print NaNs to console, whereas histogram will mark them directly on the plot
- Both will set NaN values to zero before plotting; in example below, all related non-NaN weights were already zero

[image]

Comment: First of all, great work! However looking through this I feel like this is a great tool for debugging monitoring sequential models for any undesirable behaviors/errors. But is there an interpretability component here? For example, can you extract insights from the visualizations of what the model has learned?

Comment: @thushv89 Thanks; excellent question - but as much as I myself seek it, no satisfactory answer. The principal difference between timeseries and images is that former models a _process_, whereas latter models a _state_ - so signal information is inherently more complex. Signal analysis, surely, is the main toolkit, but not complete for NNs -- [this 2019 book](https://sci-hub.se/10.1007/978-3-030-28954-6) is the best material I found on the topic. (Clarification: "signal" assuming working w/ signal data - else for NLP & word embeddings, stuff complicates yet further)

Comment: @thushv89 The [iNNvestigate](https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate) repo is better suited for interpretability, and is actually authored by the linked textbook's authors

Comment: Awesome! I really liked the topics in the book. Thanks a lot for sharing that!!! Wasn't aware of it before. Will also check out the repo. :)