# How to write the code to avoid the error of 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session' and 'global_variables_initializer'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp, google-colaboratory

Trying to run a sample code for a Named Entity Recognition model as apractice.

The reference article is: [Named Entity Recognition (NER) with keras and tensorflow](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-ner-meeting-industrys-requirement-by-applying-state-of-the-art-deep-698d2b3b4ede)

github: https://github.com/nxs5899/Named-Entity-Recognition_DeepLearning-keras

However, I have stacked with version difference of tensorflow version.

Since I'm not familiar with Tensorflow, I cannot modify the sample code following the description of the change.

I'd also appreciate it if you could share helpful articles or GitHub to build a Named Entity Recognition model with original data.

### Error Message

```
---> 11 sess = tf.Session()
     12 K.set_session(sess)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'
```

### Working Code

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras.backend import eval

X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = train_test_split(new_X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=2018)
batch_size = 32
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from keras import backend as K
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

elmo_model = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
```

### What I tried to do

Following the related question about [Tensorflow 2.0 - AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142951/tensorflow-2-0-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-session), I tried to fix my code, but another error was shown.

If it is because of my trial fixed code, I would like to how should I write for the new version of tensorflow.

#### Another Error

```
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'global_variables_initializer'
```

#### fixed version

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.keras.backend import eval

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = train_test_split(new_X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=2018)
batch_size = 32
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from keras import backend as K
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
K.set_session(sess)

elmo_model = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
```

Comment: The code you are trying to run was written for TensorFlow v1.x, and you are using TF v2.x.  See that answer for the [differences between TF1 and TF2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59112528/7370153), and the [guide to migrate](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) (if you want to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute your code in Tensorflow 2.x, you can try as shown below

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

X_tr, X_te, y_tr, y_te = train_test_split(new_X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=2018)

elmo_model = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2", trainable=True)
```