# I don't understand pytorch input sizes of conv1d, conv2d

Tags: python, input, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a data of 2 temporal series of 18 points each one. So I organized in a matrix of 18 rows and 2 columns (with 180 samples to classify in 2 classes - activated and non-activated).

So, I want to do a CNN with this data, my kernel walks in one direction, along the lines (temporal). Examples of the figure attached.

[My data 18x2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooEU0.png)

In my code, I don't know how channels I have, in comparison to RGB with 3 channels.  And don't know the input sizes of the layers, and how to calculate to know the fully connected layer.

I need to use conv1d ? conv2d? conv3d ? 
Based on [Understand conv 1D 2D 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883547/intuitive-understanding-of-1d-2d-and-3d-convolutions-in-convolutional-neural-n), I have 2D inputs and I want to do 1D convolution (because I move my kernel in one direction), is it correct ?

How I pass the kernel size (3,2) for example?

My data is in this form, after using DataLoader with batch_size= 4:

```
print(data.shape, label.shape)
```

torch.Size([4, 2, 18]) torch.Size([4, 1])

My Convolutional Model is:

OBS: I just put any number of input/output size.

```
# Creating our CNN Model -> 1D convolutional with 2D input (HbO, HbR)

class ConvModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=1,  out_channels= 18, kernel_size=3, stride = 1)
# I dont know the in/out channels of the first conv
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=3, stride=3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(18, 32, kernel_size=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(200, 100)  #What I put in/out here ?
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(100, 50)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(50, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.mp(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = F.relu(self.mp(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = x.view(-1, ??)  # flatten the tensor, which number here ?

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x
```

Answer (score 8):

You will want to use a two channel conv1d as the first convolution later. I.e. it will take in a tensor of shape [B, 2, 18]. Having 2 channel input with kernel size 3 will define kernels of shape [2, 3] where the kernel slides along the last dimension of the input. The number of channels C1 in your output feature map is up to you. C1 defines how many independent [2, 3] kernels you learn. Each convolution with a [2, 3] kernel produces an output channel.

Note that if you don't define any zero padding during conv1d then the output for a size 3 kernel will be reduced by 2, i.e. you will get [B, C1, 16]. If you include a padding of 1 (which effectively pads both sides of input with a column of zeros before convolving) then the output would be [B, C1, 18].

Max-pooling doesn't change the number of channels. If you use a kernel size of 3, stride of 3, and no padding then the last dimension will be reduced down to `floor(x.size(2) / 3)` where `x` is the input tensor to the max-pooling layer. If the input isn't a multiple of 3 then the values at the end of `x` feature map will be ignored (AKA a kernel/window alignment issue).

I recommend taking a look at the documentation for `nn.Conv1d` and `nn.MaxPool1d` since it provides equations to compute the output shape.

---

Let's consider two examples. You can define `C1, C2, F1, F2` however you like. The optimal values will depend on your data.

Without padding we get

```
class ConvModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        # input [B, 2, 18]
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=2, out_channels=C1, kernel_size=3)
        # [B, C1, 16]
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=3, stride=3)
        # [B, C1, 5]    (WARNING last column of activations in previous layer are ignored b/c of kernel alignment)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(C1, C2, kernel_size=3)
        # [B, C2, 3]
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(C2*3, F1)
        # [B, F1]
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(F1, F2)
        # [B, F2]
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(F2, 2)
        # [B, 2]

    def forward(x):
        x = F.relu(self.mp(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = F.relu(self.mp(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = x.flatten(1) # flatten the tensor starting at dimension 1

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x
```

Notice the kernel alignment issue with the max-pooling layer. This occurs because the input to max-pooling isn't a multiple of 3. To avoid the kernel alignment issue and to make output sizes more consistent I recommend including an additional padding of 1 to both the convolution layers. Then you would have

```
class ConvModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        # input [B, 2, 18]
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=2, out_channels=C1, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        # [B, C1, 18]
        self.maxpool = nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=3, stride=3)
        # [B, C1, 6]    (no alignment issue b/c 18 is a multiple of 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(C1, C2, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        # [B, C2, 6]
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(C2*6, F1)
        # [B, F1]
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(F1, F2)
        # [B, F2]
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(F2, 2)
        # [B, 2]

    def forward(x):
        x = F.relu(self.mp(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = F.relu(self.mp(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.maxpool(x)

        x = x.flatten(1) # flatten the tensor starting at dimension 1

        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x
```