# Error with the dimension of 1DConv input when using tf.data and mode.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using TensorFlow 2.0.0 and trying to create my own data set with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()

Here are my codes:

```py
def trainDatagen():
    for npy in train_list:
        x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.load(npy), dtype=tf.float32)
        if npy in gbmlist:
             y = to_categorical(0, num_classes=2)
        else:
             y = to_categorical(1, num_classes=2)
        yield x, y

def tfDatasetGen(datagen, output_types, is_training, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=datagen, output_types=output_types)
    if is_training:
        dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100)
    dataset.repeat()
    dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size)
    dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

train_set = tfDatasetGen(
    datagen = trainDatagen, 
    output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32), 
    is_training = True, 
    batch_size = 16)
```

All those npy files are np.array with shape of [4000,2048] got from large pathology slides with 4000 tiles. Feature of each tile was calculated by ResNet50.

Here is my model:

```py
def top_k(inputs, k):
    return tf.nn.top_k(inputs, k=k, sorted=True).values

def least_k(inputs, k):
    return -tf.nn.top_k(-inputs, k=k, sorted=True).values

def minmax_k(inputs, k):
    return tf.concat([top_k(inputs, k), least_k(inputs, k)], axis = -1)

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(4000,2048))
y = layers.Conv1D(1, 2048, use_bias=False, padding='same', data_format='channels_last')(inputs)
y = layers.Flatten()(y)
y = layers.Lambda(minmax_k, arguments={'k': 5})(y)
y = layers.Dense(units=200, activation=tf.nn.relu)(y)
y = layers.Dropout(rate=0.5)(y)
y = layers.Dense(units=100, activation=tf.nn.relu)(y)
y = layers.Dense(units=2, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(y)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=y)
```

When using model.fit() to train the model, I received this:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_4 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (4000, 2048)
```

All this idea is from the paper **arXiv:1802.02212**. Here is the figure of the neural network I tried to reproduce.

[image: description of CHOWDER architecture]

---

I followed Mahsa Hassankashi's advice to reshape the input to **(4000,2048,1)**

```py
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.load(npy).reshape(4000,2048,1), dtype=tf.float32)
```

and modified this part to fix an error according to GitHub issues:

```py
train_set = tfDatasetGen(
    datagen = trainDatagen, 
    output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32), 
    **output_shapes = (tf.TensorShape((None,None,None)), tf.TensorShape((2,))),**
    is_training = True, 
    batch_size = 16)
```

But I got this:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  input and filter must have the same depth: 1 vs 2048
```

Finally I tried to reshape the input to **(1,4000,2048)**, this time another kind of error came to me:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Expected size[0] in [0, 1], but got 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look at train list and if it needs 2 dimensional for Convolution NN, use:

[convolution2d](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/)

[difference between 1D, 2D, and 3D convolutions in convolutional neural networks (in deep learning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883547/intuitive-understanding-of-1d-2d-and-3d-convolutions-in-convolutional-neural-n)

[CNN Dimensional](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1216535/Deep-Learning)

Otherwise for last bug:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Expected size[0] in [0, 1], but got 2
```

When the generated element is a Tensor, from_generator function would  flatten it to output_types. And this conversion will not work.

The solution is, use **from_tensors** or **from_tensor_slices**  instead of **from_generator** when the generator generates a tensor.

Please test below solutions:

Could you please test it:

1.tensorflow gpu

```
conda create --name tensorflow
activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

2.Timesteps 
According to [this](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution1d/) your convolution1d needs 3 dimensions and convolution2d needs 4.
[image]

```
input_shape = (timesteps, input_dim)
```

timesteps=1

Then reshape the X_train and X_test as:

```
X1_Train = X1_Train.reshape((4000,2048,1))
#call model.fit()
```

3.Use

```
model.fit_generator()
```

4.Add flatten before the last dense.

```
model.add(Flatten())
```

[keras convolution_layers](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/)

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I followed your advice to reshape the input array:
`x = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.load(npy).reshape((4000,2048,1)), dtype=tf.float32)`
Then it raised another error: 
`371 def validate_all_tensor_shapes(x, x_values):
    
372   # Validate that the shape of all the elements in x have the same shape
--> 373   x_shape = x_values[0].shape.as_list()
    374   for i in range(1, len(x_values)):
    375     if x_shape != x_values[i].shape.as_list(): 
ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape. `

Comment: Great let me know about your output.

Comment: @Satantango Are you sure it is conv1?

Comment: Yes. Here's the description given in the eassay: _First, a set of one-dimensional embeddings for the P = 2048 ResNet-50 features are calcualted via J one-dimensional convolutional layers strided across the tile index axis_ .