# RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight [64, 512, 1], but got 2-dimensional input of size [4, 512] instead

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Hello below is the pytorch model I am trying to run. But getting error. I have posted the error trace as well. It was running very well unless I added convolution layers. I am still new to deep learning and Pytorch. So I apologize if this is silly question. I am using conv1d so why should conv1d expect 3 dimensional input and it is also getting a 2d input which is also odd.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(CROP_SIZE*CROP_SIZE*3, 512)
            self.conv1d1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=512, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1, stride=2)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 128)
            self.conv1d2 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1, stride=2)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 256)
            self.conv1d3 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=256, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1, stride=2)
            self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, 256)
            self.fc4 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
            self.fc5 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
            self.fc6 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
            self.fc7 = nn.Linear(32, 64)
   

     self.fc8 = nn.Linear(64, frame['landmark_id'].nunique())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1d1(self.fc1(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.conv1d2(self.fc2(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.conv1d3(self.fc3(x)))
        x = F.relu(self.fc4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc6(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc7(x))
        x = self.fc8(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)


net = Net()

import torch.optim as optim

loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
net.to(torch.device('cuda:0'))
for epoch in range(3): # 3 full passes over the data
    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    for data in tqdm(train_loader):  # `data` is a batch of data
        X = data['image'].to(device)  # X is the batch of features
        y = data['landmarks'].to(device) # y is the batch of targets.
        optimizer.zero_grad()  # sets gradients to 0 before loss calc. You will do this likely every step.
        output = net(X.view(-1,CROP_SIZE*CROP_SIZE*3))  # pass in the reshaped batch
#         print(np.argmax(output))
#         print(y)
        loss = F.nll_loss(output, y)  # calc and grab the loss value
        loss.backward()  # apply this loss backwards thru the network's parameters
        optimizer.step()  # attempt to optimize weights to account for loss/gradients

    print(loss)  # print loss. We hope loss (a measure of wrong-ness) declines!
```

Error trace

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-f5ed7999ce57> in <module>
      5         y = data['landmarks'].to(device) # y is the batch of targets.
      6         optimizer.zero_grad()  # sets gradients to 0 before loss calc. You will do this likely every step.
----> 7         output = net(X.view(-1,CROP_SIZE*CROP_SIZE*3))  # pass in the reshaped batch
      8 #         print(np.argmax(output))
      9 #         print(y)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

<ipython-input-37-6d3e34d425a0> in forward(self, x)
     16 
     17     def forward(self, x):
---> 18         x = F.relu(self.conv1d1(self.fc1(x)))
     19         x = F.relu(self.conv1d2(self.fc2(x)))
     20         x = F.relu(self.conv1d3(self.fc3(x)))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    549         else:
--> 550             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    551         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    552             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    210                             _single(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    211         return F.conv1d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 212                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    213 
    214 

RuntimeError: Expected 3-dimensional input for 3-dimensional weight [64, 512, 1], but got 2-dimensional input of size [4, 512] instead
```

Answer (score 2):

You should learn how convolutions work (e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44628011/10886420)) and some neural network basics ([this tutorial from PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/deep_learning_60min_blitz.html)).

Basically, `Conv1d` expects inputs of shape `[batch, channels, features]` (where `features` can be some timesteps and can vary, see example).

`nn.Linear` expects shape `[batch, features]` as it is fully connected and each input feature is connected to each output feature.

You can verify those shapes by yourself, for `torch.nn.Linear`:

```
import torch

layer = torch.nn.Linear(20, 10)
data = torch.randn(64, 20)  # [batch, in_features]
layer(data).shape  # [64, 10], [batch, out_features]
```

For `Conv1d`:

```
layer = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=20, out_channels=10, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
data = torch.randn(64, 20, 15)  # [batch, channels, timesteps]
layer(data).shape  # [64, 10, 15], [batch, out_features]

layer(torch.randn(32, 20, 25)).shape  # [32, 10, 25]
```

**BTW.** As you are working with images, you should use `torch.nn.Conv`**2**`d` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the **Pytorch** functions work on **batch** data i.e they accept input of size `(batch_size, shape)`. @Szymon Maszke already posted answer related to that.

So in your case, you can use **unsqueeze** and **sqeeze** functions for adding and removing extra dimensions.

Here's the sample code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(100, 512)
        self.conv1d1 = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=512, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1, stride=2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 128)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = x.unsqueeze(dim=2)
        x = F.relu(self.conv1d1(x))
        x = x.squeeze()

        x = self.fc2(x)

        return x


net = Net()

bsize = 4
inp   = torch.randn((bsize, 100))

out = net(inp)
print(out.shape)
```