# How to define specific number of convolutional kernels/filters in pytorch?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

On pytorch website they have the following model in their tutorial

```
class BasicCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BasicCNN, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

How many kernels/filters this model has? Is it two - e.g conv1 and conv2. How do I easily create many filters by specifying the number of them? For example 100 filters.

Thanks!

Comment: The input and output channels are parameters of nn.Conv2d. They effectively determine the number of filters and dimensions of data volume flowing through your network. Read more here: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html I've also created an implementation of a 2D convolution on a 3D RGB image that you could use to play around with this and get some intuition. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62678843/5484902

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous but let me try to answer it.

Usually, in a convolutional layer, we set the number of filters as the number of `out_channels`. But this is not straight-forward. Let's discuss based on the example that you provided.

> What are the convolutional layer parameters?

```
model = BasicCNN()
for name, params in model.named_parameters():
    if 'conv' in name:
        print(name, params.size())
```

Output:

```
conv1.weight torch.Size([6, 3, 5, 5])
conv1.bias torch.Size([6])
conv2.weight torch.Size([16, 6, 5, 5])
conv2.bias torch.Size([16])
```

> Explanation

Let's consider `conv1` layer in the above model. We can say, there are 6 filters of shape `3 x 5 x 5` because we have chosen 2d Convolution and the number of input channels is 3. So there are in total 6 kernels.

Here, the inputs of this model are 3d like images. You can consider, we have images with shape `W x H` and there are 3 channels (RGB) for images. So, we can feed 3d tensors representing images to this model.

---

Now coming back to your question, "How do I easily create many filters by specifying the number of them? For example 100 filters.". If you want to simply use 100 filters per input channel, then just set 100 in `conv1` instead of `6`. This is typically what people do in computer vision!

But you can definitely modify the architecture as per your need and identify the best setting.